# Object reference behaviour

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In below snippet, i have two variables `firstString` and `secondString` which holds same value **"Hello"**. So the referenced location for both variables are same.

```
var firstString = "Hello";
var secondString = "Hello";
bool isSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, secondString);
//same reference for both variables
```

But updating `secondString` value as **"Hey"** does not update the `firstString`,even though it referes to the same location. Why these variables are not getting updated which refers to the same reference location?

```
secondString = "Hey..";
isSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, secondString); 
//reference changed but firstString not updated
```

Updating `secondString` to it's pervious value as **"Hello"** makes the reference same.

```
secondString = "Hello";
isSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, secondString); 
//now the reference for both variables are same
```

Why c# has this behaviour and how frmaework internaly handling this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you observing the 'reference' and what has led you to the assumption that both strings are stored at the same address?

Comment: A `secondString = "-Hello".Substring(1);` would give a different reference.

Comment: @Gusdor using the Object.ReferenceEquals method

Comment: in fact this behavior is determined by **how the compiler optimizes the string data**, all the strings of the **same values** in your project will use the same **physical** memory, because string is **immuatable** or **readonly**, we don't need different memory to store the same string values. It's some kind of optimization, although we know that **string** is reference type in .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process called interning. You can read more on strings interning [there](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html). This made to save some space and processing time when allocating new sting with exact same content as already existing one. Also stings interning makes strings comparsion trivial operation. This is possible since `String` is immutable type.

Answer (score 1):

You did not updating the string, you updated the reference to a string, which now points to "hey…" that does not include the reference to the string "Hello" of firstString.Furthermore  ,the "compiler" of c# collects every static string in your code in a list without doublets, thats the reason why two different "Hello"s on different places are the same string if you compare the reference to them.

Answer (score 0):

C# (.NET) holds every string literal only one time in the .NET heap. "Hello" and "Hey..." strings are stored in two different locations on the .NET heap. Initially, firstString and secondString point both to the "Hello" location. secondString = "Hey.."; just change the secondString variable to point to the location on heap where "Hey..." is located. You should be aware that a string variable holds the address(reference) of the place in heap where the string is really located.